# How to sort the words of a single cell in an SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-parsing, sql-server-2016-express

For example:

- Pillars 101 in an apartment
- Zuzu Durga International Hotel
- Wyndham Garden Fresh Meadows

Need to sort the above as,

- 101 an apartment in Pillars
- Durga Hotel International Zuzu
- Fresh Garden Meadows Wyndham

Comment: This is not a typical requirement in most database work.  You never told us which DB you are using, but most likely you would need a UDF for this.  The atomic unit of work in a table is usually the cell itself.

Comment: This is incredibly difficult to achieve. For example, there are cases where place name is not simply a single word (eg: New York). So you can't simply substring it. Do you have a list/table with place names?

Comment: Am using SQL server 2016 and I need to sort the values in each cell of a particular column. Example as defined above. Is there any predefined function to sort alpha numeric words?

Comment: @HoneyBadger YEah I do have it. Its' okay if it sort the city name in the content (eg: San Mateo - Mateo San)

Comment: @Abynez There are no words in a *field*. It's just a string value with text. Some of the characters may be `,` or ` ` or ``. That doesn't mean they have any special meaning or ordering. You have a fundamental design bug - breaking 1st Normal Form to store multiple items in a single field. Fix the bug.

Comment: @Abynez on the other hand, assuming the contents have no special meaning and thus can't/shouldn't appear as fields or records, you could use SQL Server's JSON support and store the data as a JSON array. Then use the JSON functions to retrieve individual values. For existing data you could use `REPLACE` to replace spaces with `','` and wrap the result in `['`, ']`, converting it to a JSON array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's nothing that you can do natively. If you want to sort the values just as a *return* value, i.e. not update the database itself, you can transform the results with either a stored procedure or perhaps a view.

So let's construct an answer.

Let's just assume you want to do it visually, for a single row. If you have SQL 2016 you can use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) but SQL Fiddle doesn't, so I used a common UDF [fnSplitString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791740/convert-comma-separated-value-to-rows)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7194d/2

`SELECT value
FROM fnSplitString('Pillars 101 in an apartment', ' ')
WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '';`

That gives me each word, split out. What about ordering it?

`SELECT value
FROM fnSplitString('Pillars 101 in an apartment', ' ')
WHERE RTRIM(value) <> ''
ORDER BY value;`

And if I want to do it for each row in the DB table I have? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7194d/8

`SELECT split.value
FROM [Data] d
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString(IsNull(d.Value,''), ' ') AS split
WHERE RTRIM(split.value) <> ''
ORDER BY value;`

That's sort of helpful, except now all my words are jumbled. Let's go back to our original query and identify each row. Each row probably has an Identity column on it. If so, you've got your grouping there. If not, you can use ROW_NUMBER, such as:

`SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.Value) AS [Identity] -- here, use identity instead of row_number
  , d.Value
FROM [Data] d`

If we then use this query as a subquery in our select, we get:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7194d/21

`SELECT d.[Identity], split.value
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.Value) AS [Identity] -- here, use identity instead of row_number
      , d.Value
    FROM [Data] d
  ) d
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString(IsNull(d.Value,''), ' ') AS split
WHERE RTRIM(split.value) <> ''
ORDER BY d.[Identity], value;`

This query now sorts all rows within each identity. But now you need to reconstruct those individual words back into a single string, right? For that, you can use [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql). In my example I use a [CTE because of SQL Fiddle limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445102/create-and-use-temp-table-in-nested-queries) but you could use a temp table, too.

`WITH tempData AS (
  SELECT d.[Identity], split.value
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.Value) AS [Identity] -- here, use identity instead of row_number
        , d.Value
      FROM [Data] d
    ) d
  CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString(IsNull(d.Value,''), ' ') AS split
  WHERE RTRIM(split.value) <> ''
  )
SELECT grp.[Identity]
  , STUFF((SELECT N' ' + [Value] FROM tempData WHERE [Identity] = grp.[Identity] ORDER BY Value FOR XML PATH(N''))
            , 1, 1, N'')
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Identity] FROM tempData) AS grp`

Here's the end result fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7194d/27

As expressed in comments already, **this is not a common case for SQL**. It's an unnecessary burden on the server. I would recommend pulling data out of SQL and sorting it through your programming language of choice; or making sure it's sorted as you insert it into the DB. I went through the exercise because I had a few minutes to kill :)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('Pillars 101 in an apartment')
,('Zuzu Durga International Hotel')
,('Wyndham Garden Fresh Meadows');

SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT YourString AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).query
('
    for $x in /x
    order by $x
    return
    concat($x/text()[1], " ")   
').value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM @tbl;
```

The code will frist transfer your text in an XML like `<x>Pillars</x><x>101</x> ...`.
Then a `FLWOR XQuery` is used to return the text parts sorted.
The last call to `.value()` will return the sorted fragments as text again.

The result

```
101  Pillars  an  apartment  in 
Durga  Hotel  International  Zuzu 
Fresh  Garden  Meadows  Wyndham
```

### Final statement

This code is kind of an exercise. Your design is really bad and should be changed...

Comment: I dig it. A more direct way at what I was trying to provide in my exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Already +1 on Shnugo's solution.  I actually watch for his posts.

Just another option use a parse UDF in concert with a Cross Apply.

**Example**

```
Select B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select Sorted=Stuff((Select ' ' +RetVal From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](A.SomeCol,' ') Order By RetVal For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')  )B
```

**Returns**

```
Sorted
101 an apartment in Pillars
Durga Hotel International Zuzu
Fresh Garden Meadows Wyndham
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your support and just a tiny hint: It's fine to have the parser *XML safe*, but without `,TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)')` Your output would not be re-escaped :-D You're moving quickly by the way!

Comment: @Shnugo Tremendous eye!   I'll make the update in a few.